# JSP - issue with custom Taglib

Tags: java, jsp

I just tried to add a custom taglib to my project, such that the `testtaglib.tld` file contains:

```
<taglib>
<tlibversion>1.0</tlibversion>
  <jspversion>1.1</jspversion>
  <shortname>name</shortname>

    <tag>
        <name>test</name>
        <tagclass>taglib.TestTaglib</tagclass>
        <bodycontent>empty</bodycontent>
        <attribute>
            <name>testCode</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
            <type>java.lang.String</type>
        </attribute>
    </tag>
<taglib>
```

And then I added taglib class `TestTaglib.java`

```
public class TestTaglib extends TagSupport {

    private String  testCode;
    public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
        try {
            JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
            //doing some conversion with testCode
            out.print(testCode);
            return EVAL_PAGE;
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            throw new JspException("Error: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And then in `.jsp` file

```
<name:test testCode="${testCode}"/>
```

Okay the issue is:`TestTaglib.java` is recognizing values of `testCode` as `${testCode}` and not the original value. Any suggestion?

Comment: upgrade <jsp-version>2.0</jsp-version>.

Comment: @AmitParashar, thanks for your valuable time, any documentation saying like that? just to make sure..

Comment: Refer wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Expression_Language

Comment: @AmitParashar, I agreed, let me check, thanks a lot

Comment: @AmitParashar, just for clarification, but in jsp's `<c:out value="${myBean.myField}" />` is working without any issue, does that makes sense

Comment: The jsp version in your tag does not conforms to JSP 2.0, your jsp may have a higher version. Please let me know whether upgrade helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80810/discussion-between-amit-parashar-and-suganthan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi all inbuilt tag already handles the expression language. Just change your code as mentioned below and it will work fine.

```
 public class TestTaglib extends TagSupport {


 private String  testCode;
    public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
        try {
            JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
            //doing some conversion with testCode
            String value = (String) ExpressionUtil.evalNotNull("test", "testCode", testCode, String.class, this, pageContext);
            out.print(value);
            return EVAL_PAGE;
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            throw new JspException("Error: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

ExpressionUtil is class provided under org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core package.

Here is short desc of evalNotNull method args

**1) tagName :** your tag name is test
**2) tagAttribute:** to eval in your case it is testCode
**3) expression :** which is el expression ${testCode}
**4) Value:** Class of expression value whether it is Boolean,String or any Object
**5) tagClass:** Reference of tag handler class so you can pass this
**6) pageContext:** which is coming from TagSupport